# Intellij Idea Follow JAR/library Dependency Chain

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a module that depends on a module that in turn depends on an external jar file / library (tried both options in intellij), (red path in image).

How can I make this JAR file automatically be added to the uppermost module by just marking the middle module as a dependency, (blue path)?

For reference, the error I'm getting in the outer module is `Cannot access xxx.xxx.xxx`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6F36.png

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a artifact parent for each of your modules, all your dependencies in that parent and import the parent to your module dependency.
For example -

```
 - Module1
         - (package) artifact parent
                - parent-pom.xml ==> includes external and internal dependencies
         - pom.xml ==> inherits parent pom
 - Module2
         - (package) artifact parent
                - parent-pom.xml ==> includes external dependencies
         - pom.xml ==> inherits parent pom  and has Module 1 dependency
```

Similarly, you can do it for the other modules. You'll have to add each dependency in the dependent module